# Mongoose: unique index on pair of fields in either combination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose, unique

Uniqueness on multiple fields might often mean that you can't have documents with identical combinations of certain fields, like `name1` and `name2`. So it would disallow two documents existing which both have `{name1: 'Joe', name2: 'Bob'}`.

This still allows documents to exist simultaneously if they have `name1` and `name2` switched, for example `{name1: 'Bob', name2: 'Joe'}` and `{name1: 'Joe', name2: 'Bob'}`.

Is there a way to make a unique index which does NOT allow those both? (If `{name1: 'Bob', name2: 'Joe'}` exists, neither `{name1: 'Bob', name2: 'Joe'}` nor `{name1: 'Joe', name2: 'Bob'}` can be inserted.)

Comment: It doesn't work like that as you should have already concluded. If you need that in "combination" then an "array" would be a better choice than individual keys. Or basically anything that combined into the **one** property. A "compound" index with "unique" is still really *"unique on each property"*, and **not** on the "combination"

Comment: Of course the catch with an "array" would be that there could only ever be **one** `"Bob"` and the catch with a "compound string" is that `Bob#Joe` is   still different to `Joe#Bob`. So this isn't really something you can solve with "indexes". You can use an `$or` condition on an "upsert" to match on either order, and wrap any "insertion" logic within `$setOnInsert` only, but your whole case is not that clear of what to do on "insertion" or on a "match". But generally speaking, upserts "should" be the way to handle this rather than just by index.

Comment: Oooh, I did not realize that about the *"unique on each property"* thing. Thank you. I edited the question to remove that mistake.